# How do you change the site template from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: template

My current environement is in SharePoint 2010 but some sites still have the 2007 look and feel. How do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

As Eric said, you need to perform visual upgrade. Here is the PowerShell script which iterates through all site collections in a Web application and perform Visual upgrades.

```
#iterates though all the site collections
    $Mywebapplication = Get-SPWebApplication "http://myserverWebApplication1"
    [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
    foreach($site in $Mywebapplication.Sites)
    {

            foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
            {  
                write-host "In the Site Collection URL " $site.Url  "## In the web Named " $web.Name -foregroundcolor Yellow
                $web.UIVersion = 4
                $web.UIVersionConfigurationEnabled = 1
                $web.Update();                
                $web.Dispose();
            }          
            $site.Dispose();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Site Collection Administrators need to to go Site Actions, Site Settings and trigger the Visual Upgrade.